# How do I handle timeouts when using ActiveMerchant?

Tags: timeout, activemerchant

Sometimes when developing locally my connection drops, and whilst this hopefully shouldn't happen on production it raises an issue that I should probably handle timeouts from ActiveMerchant when it goes out to the payment gateway, in my case to SagePay.

I can't see a way in the documentation to do this, I was wondering if there was a best practice way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the question is connected to ruby implementation of AM (correct me if I'm wrong, please).

`ActiveMerchant` raises `ActiveMerchant::ConnectionError` when timeout occurs ([link to source](https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant/blob/424fa8d613da6e720bfed005aa33f2b5dced5ca4/lib/active_merchant/network_connection_retries.rb#L32)). Therefore we can simply handle the exception. e.g.:

```
begin
  # Your ActiveMerchant staff here
rescue ActiveMerchant::ConnectionError => e
  # timeout handler
end
```

Also sometimes it can be useful to control the timeouts using `open_timeout` and `read_timeout` class attributes ([link to source](https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant/blob/master/lib/active_merchant/posts_data.rb)), in case of `SagePay`:

```
ActiveMerchant::SagePay.open_timeout = 5 # timeout for opening the connection is set to 5 seconds
ActiveMerchant::SagePay.read_timeout = 10 # timeout for reading from opened connection is set to 10
```